# Analytic Function with positive integers as zeros?

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Do you know any nontrivial analytic function f(z) with zeros **only** at positive integer values of the argument z = 1, 2, 3, 4, ... ? 
If yes, please give some example.

PS: I already thought of $f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(-x+1)}$. Any other nice options?

EDIT: To avoid trivial solutions due to restriction of definition range, please consider the required function to be defined in the whole complex plane.

Comment: What about $\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{z}$?

Comment: @Pragabhava : your function has zeros at $z=\pm 1,~\pm 2,~\pm 3,~...$

Comment: Right, Didn't thought about the negative ones. As I did with the zero: $\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\Pi_0^\infty (z + n)}$, but now I'm not sure about the analiticity (I think it is). If not, how about removing the negative ones using the $\Gamma$ function? They are of order one.

Comment: @Pragabhava: nice idea to use $\Gamma$ to remove zeros, but somehow it does not really enrich the pool of functions with that property...

Comment: If you already have an example, then what is it that you're looking for in additional examples that isn't already provided by the one you have?

Comment: Ok, then how about this idea: Take something like $H(1-z) + \frac{1}{2} \sin(\pi z)$, but instead of the Heaviside function, use a proper [mollifier like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All other entire functions $f$ with simple zeros exactly at positive integers differ from your $f_o(z)=1/\Gamma(-z+1)$ by a function of the form $e^{g(z)}$ for entire $g$, and vice-versa. That is, $f(z)=f_o(z) \cdot e^{g(z)}$ for entire $g$, and vice-versa. Indeed: $f(z)/f_o(z)$ has no zeros and is entire, so is of the form $e^{g(z)}$, since we can define its logarithm.

Comment: Very nice proof! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

$$
\zeta(-2x)+\sin(\pi x),
$$
but $x \neq 0.109737160708907...$

Answer (score 1):

Denote $(p \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\})$ 
$$E\left({z},\, p\right)=\begin{cases}1-z, & p=0, \\ (1-z)e^{z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\ldots+\frac{z^p}{p}}, & p\geqslant{1}. \end{cases}$$ 
Function $E\left({z},\, p\right)$ is called by *primary* or *elementary Weierstrass factor* of genus $p$.
Let $\{a_\nu \} \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a sequence of non-zero complex numbers such that $|{a_\nu}| \rightarrow \infty.$
Then function $$f(z)=\prod\limits_{\nu=1}^{\infty}{E\left(\dfrac{z}{a_\nu},\, p\right)}$$ called as [*Weierstrass canonical product*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem), is entire function that has zeroes at points $a_\nu$ and only at them.

Answer (score 1):

$$ f(x) = 3^x - 2^x $$
has 0 as a zero.
$$ f(x) = 4^x - 2 \cdot 3^x + 2^x$$
has 0 and 1 as a zero.
$$ f(x) = 5^x - 3\cdot4^x + 3\cdot3^x - 2^x $$
has 0, 1, and 2 as a zero.
$$ f(x) =  6^x - 4\cdot5^x + 6\cdot4^x - 4\cdot3^x + 2^x $$
has 0, 1, 2, and 3 as a zero.

See the pattern. Continuing

$$ f(x) = 7^x - 5\cdot6^x+10\cdot5^x-10\cdot4^x+5\cdot3^x-2^x$$
has 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 as a zero.

$$ f(x) = 8^x-6\cdot7^x+15\cdot6^x-20\cdot5^x+15\cdot4^x-6\cdot3^x+2^x $$
has 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 as a zero.

The pattern is the base decreases by one. Signs alternate. The coefficients are the numbers of the Pascal's triangle.