# Construct an entire function whose only zeroes are following

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, entire-functions

This question is from Ponnusamy and Silvermann Complex Variables pg 436, subsection wietestrauss product theorem

> Question: Construct an entire function whose only zeroes are z=ln n.

Weierstrauss Product theorem guarentees that such a function exists, I thought of sin ($\pi z$) but it's zeroes will also be -1,-2,... . Similar problem is also for cos z and tan z.

Also, there are similar questions in same exercise wich ask for zeroes only at z=n of multiplicity n , zeroes only at z=$n^{3/4}$ .

Is there any general approach to these type of questions?

If yes kindly share. If no just answer 1 series asked.

Thanks!

Edit:there are similar questions in same exercise wich ask for zeroes only at z=n of multiplicity n.

There is an example before the exercise in which It is proved that an entire function woth zeroes only at z=+ve integers is $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-z/n) e^{z/n}$ and I adapted that proof to see if $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-z/n)^n e^{z/n}$ will be the polynomial asked in this but the mentioned product is not uniformly convergent product. So, I need an convergence producing factor which was $e^{z/n}$ in case of roots only at z=+ve integers. Can you please tell me how can I find such a convergence producing factor.

Also, I have solved the entire function with zeroes only at z=$n^{3/4}$ but not the above mentioned part in which I am unable to find the convergence producing factor.

> Also ,this method used for entire function whose zeroes are only +ve integers can't be applied on ln (n) as the series $1\(ln n)^p $ diverges for all p .
> So, No progress can be made on this part.

Kindly help.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/211674/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3694769/42969

Comment: $f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-z/n)e^{z/n}$ is easily seen to be entire. It is a theorem that $f(z)= e^{cz}/\Gamma(1-z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you changed your question.. Take $k_n$ such that  $$\sup_{|z|\le \frac12 \log n} |\log(1-z/\log n)+\sum_{m=1}^{k_n} \frac{(z/\log n)^m}{m}|\le 2^{-n}$$
(can you remind us why it exists ?)

Then $$\prod_{n\ge 2} (1-z/\log n) \exp(\sum_{m=1}^{k_n} \frac{(z/\log n)^m}{m})$$ is entire.

(can you remind us why ?)

Comment: Can you please tell why the function in your answer is entire. I am not able to understand that

Comment: Because it converges locally uniformly. Local uniform convergence implies analyticity is Morera's theorem.